# Youtube Video Gallery

Tags: magento-1.7, gallery

I need a video gallery page in Magento Community 1.7 and found the plugin [Youtube Video Gallery](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/youtube-video-gallery-1.html) from magentocommerce.com.  And I have a problem with this plugin. When I access the configuration page of the plugin I get 404 error. Any ideas how to make it  work?

Comment: Log out and log in again.

Comment: :D What is with this magic? I spent a day on this. Thanks!

Comment: I added more details about it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common practice and a way to solve it.
**Log out a from the admin and login again.**
This is neede because the ACL is kept in the admin session.
Before installing the extension you have access to the existing sections of the configuration.
But while you installed the extension a new section was added to the config screen, that you don't have access to.
Re-logging in rebuilds the access list and you get access to the newly added configuration section.

Comment: If you don't wants to logout and than login, you can also resolve this by saving current logged in user Role (eg:"Administrator") role from Magento Admin >> System >> Permission >> Roles :)

Comment: @BijalBhavsar. I don't think that works. not always anyway.

Comment: we usually do this :)